# Hide Check box and Radio Buttons and use CSS

Tags: css, checkbox, radio-button

I am trying to create some Radio Buttons and Check Boxes that use CSS for styling and hide them.  But i am running into being able to position them. I can get the buttons and boxes to disappear and change the look depending on being activated or not, but when i go to place them for example 100px from left and 100px down they dont move they stay in line.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
#COM1TX {
 left:200px;
 top:500px;
 position:relative
 
}
#COMRX {
 left: 0px;
 top: 100x;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: crosshair;
}
.radios .radio{
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 left: 200px;
 top: 500px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 line-height: 100px;
 text-align: center;
}
.radios input[type=radio]{ 
    display:none;
}

.radios input[type=radio]:checked + .radio{
 background-color: #ffffff;
 color: #000000;
 line-height: 100px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="TEST2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="radios">
<input type="radio" name="COMTX" id="COM1TX">
<label class="radio" for="COM1TX">COM 1 Tx</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="COMRX" id="COMRX">
<label for="COMRX">COM 1,2 Rx</label>
</div>
<div class="radios">
<input type="radio" name="COMTX" id="COM2TX">
<label class="radio" for="COM2TX">COM 2 Tx</label>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm unclear on what should be positioned where. Can you elaborate or show a picture that better illustrates the problem?

Comment: Try to style `div` or `label` instead of `input'

Answer (score 0):

use `position: relative` here and you will be able to move them wherever you want

```
 .radios .radio{
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        left: 200px;
        top: 8px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/11w5rpju/1/)**

Comment: That is a little closer to what im looking for but i need them to be spaced down a little bit.  The spacing is 840px from the left of the document and the buttons start about 105px from the top.  i have 2 radio buttons and the rest are check boxes.  I would add a picture but not sure how to do it in a comment.

Comment: Here is the fiddle for it. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/hn1tett7/) notice next to the  XXX.XXX and below the smaller numbers thats where i would like them to start.